# Forced to use forward declaration even though the header of the class was already included

Tags: c++, class

I have a weird issue in a C++ code and I cannot figure out what is going on. I know what a forward declaration is, and I know when to use them etc...

However, in a C++ project I have, I am forced to foward declare a class that has been already declared in an included header. It looks something like this

windows.h:

```
#ifndef WINDOWS_HH_
#define WINDOWS_HH_

#include "foo.h"

class fooC;                 // If I don't forward declare here, won't compile!?
class WindowC
{
     public:
          WindowC();
          ~WindowC();
     public:
          fooC a;
};
#endif
```

and then, foo.h contains the declaration of fooC

```
#ifndef FOO_HH_
#define FOO_HH_
class fooC
{
     public:
            fooC();
            ~fooC();
};
#endif
```

Any idea why this might be happening? The actual code is part of a big project and it is really difficult to figure out what the error might be... but I am sure that theoretically that forward declaration of fooC shouldn't be necessary, should it?

Comment: Does `foo.h` include `windows.h`, creating a circular dependency (maybe indirectly)?

Comment: Yes, it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @sth uhm... looks like you are probably right! I might have a looong indirect circular dependency... Let me have a look at it. Cheers

Comment: @Dan also, if putting `class fooC;` makes it compile, you don't need to `#include "foo.h"` at all. Just put that `#include` in the implementation file.

Comment: @SethCarnegie Right, but I always thought that forward declarations should be used as least as possible?

Comment: @Dan no haha, they should be used as **much** as possible! Why bring an entire file into the compilation process with all the stuff you don't need when you can just add a forward declaration?

Comment: @sth You were right! Indirect circular dependency. Can you post that as an answer so the question can be closed? This might help other people with the same mistake.

Comment: Don't name your header file `windows.h`, that's the same name as a very important system header file on Windows.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield I am not developing for Windows, and the names in the example are not the real ones being used hehehe. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common cause for such an effect would be a circular dependency between the header files.

Does `foo.h` include `windows.h` (maybe indirectly), creating a circular dependency?

Answer (score 0):

You need the full definition of `fooC` anyway, because it's included directly (not by pointer or reference) in `WindowC`.  Like @joval said, it shouldn't be necessary. What kind of compiler error are you getting?  I'd look for simple mistakes like forgetting include guards or semicolon after class definitions.

Comment: AFAIK, this answer is incorrect. Declaring an object variable is allowed with a forward reference. The linker requires teh full definition, of course.

Comment: This may be compiler dependent, but it definitely does not work with VS 2010.  Forward declarations work for pointer or reference types (where the size of the object is known at compile time), but definitely not for regular composition of types.

Comment: japreiss this answer it's not really helpful. I am asking WHY I need to forward declare if the header was previously already included. I know I need the full declaration, I am just asking about the need of the forward declaration.

Comment: I was trying to clarify that you shouldn't need to declare it at all, but I think the circular dependency is probably the right track.