# "Does not name a type" error, but class pointer already has forward declaration?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, forward-declaration

I am getting this compiler error

```
error: 'RawLog' does not name a type
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
//DataAudit.h
#ifndef DATAAUDIT_H
#define DATAAUDIT_H

class RawLog;

class DataAudit
{
...
private:
    RawLog* _createNewRawLog(); // This is the line indicated with the error
};

#endif // DATAAUDIT_H
```

Usually a forward declaration resolves this kind of error. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12588252/446554) answer indicates that a circular header inclusion may cause this. But doesn't the use of the `#ifndef` and `#define` statements prevent circular header inclusion?

Is there another reason I might see this error?

What are some avenues of approach I could use to further deduce the nature of this error?

**Update:** This is rather odd. I have a `Globals.h` file, and if I define a new `enum` in `Globals.h`, the error appears. Then if I comment out the `enum`, the error goes away. This leads me to think that the circular dependency has existed for a while, and adding the `enum` somehow re-orders the compilation units, thus exposing the dependency that wasn't there before?

Comment: Are you sure that this is exactly where the problem is, and you have given us a complete and reproducible example? If so, what compiler, since g++ 4.6.3 compiles it fine [once I added the missing semicolon and removed the ...].

Comment: You also forgot a `;` at the end of DataAudit. Depending on how these are included it could cause problems.

Comment: @Borgleader Ah, my bad. The semicolon is there in the original code.

Comment: @MatsPetersson That is NOT a complete and reproducible sample. I don't think the error exists in this file, I must be making a mistake somewhere else. I'm working right now on cutting down the code to just what is reproducible, but it's a rather large application and I was hoping SO had other ideas on places to look to resolve the error. Is just cutting down the code until the error disappears the only solution? I'm also trying to just backout recent code until the problem goes away... ugh.

Comment: @UchiaItachi `DataAudit.cpp` is 131 lines long... I'm not sure what would be the relevant parts for this post?

Comment: Have you double-checked that the forward declaration of `RawLog` and the class declaration of `DataAudit` are in the same namespace?

Comment: Like Phlucious says, it could still be a circular include in some way. But yeah, pretty much "Move back in time until it goes away". Do you know when it last compiled?

Comment: @Casey Good idea for something to check, but I don't even use the `namespace` keyword in this project.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Yea, I do. Unfortunately, I didn't follow the "commit early, commit often" mantra today, so I have this huge blob of changed code. I'll be able to work through it, it will just take time. I'll definitely update this answer once I figure it out too.

Comment: I'm lousy at committing changes, but I try to compile often...

Comment: @MatsPetersson Yea, I'd like to think I compile often as well, but I don't know exactly what changes I made to which files between the last time it did compile, and the last time it didn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end, I am not sure I understand completely why the error occurred, but this is what I did to resolve it, and some other related information. Maybe this will help others that come across this question.

1. For each header file in my project

   1. For each `#include "..."` in the header

      1. If there are no references to the class in the `#include`, remove it.
      2. If there are only pointers to the class defined in the `#include`, then replace it with a `class ...` forward declaration.
      3. If there is a member instance of the class defined in `#include` and it makes sense to use a pointer and allocate the member on the heap, then change the member to a pointer, and replace the `#include` with a `class ....` forward declaration.
2. Go through my `Globals.h` and move anything that can be moved out of it to more localized and specific header files.

   1. Specifically, remove an `enum` that was defined is `Globals.h`, and place it in a more localized header file.

After doing all this I was able to make the error go away. Strangely enough, the `enum` in `Globals.h` seemed to be a catalyst for the error. Whenever I removed it from `Globals.h`, the error would go away. I don't see how this `enum` could cause the error, so I think it indirectly led to the error somehow. I still wasn't able to figure out exactly how or why, but it has helped me for this guideline when coding in C++:

> Don't put anything in a header file unless it needs to be there. Don't
>   place anything in a `Globals.h` that can be placed in a more localized
>   file. Basically, do all you can to reduce the amount of code that is
>   included through the `#include` directives.

Comment: To note, `1.1.3` above may be a controversial design decision, but when you are getting into your 4th hour of debugging a similar error and it solves your problem with only minor design change, it may be worth it.

Answer (score 3):

The `#ifndef` header guard doesn't prevent circular dependencies. It just prevents multiple inclusions of the same header in a single file.

Looks like a circular dependency to me. This means you `#include` a header in DataAudit.h that `#include`s DataAudit.h either directly or indirectly.